# How can I create a canvas imageData array from an arrayBuffer representation of a JPG

Tags: javascript, canvas, arrays, filereader

First of all I am aware there are standard methods of achieving this (readAsDataURL and drawImage), but unfortunately they are not usable for this specific use case.

I am reading an image using the filereader API as an arraybuffer like so:

```
    var reader = new fileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){

          var byteArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(e.target.result);
          //do stuff to this array
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

I am then creating a clampedarray with this returned data.

What I want to be able to do is now draw this pixel array directly to a canvas using `putImageData`

Currently I am doing the following:

```
var byteArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(e.target.result);
var imgdata = ctx.createImageData(img.width, img.height);
var canvdata = imgdata.data;

for (var i = 0; i < canvdata.length; i += 4) {
    canvdata[i] = byteArray[i];
    canvdata[i + 1] = byteArray[i + 1];
    canvdata[i + 2] = byteArray[i + 2];
    canvdata[i + 3] = byteArray[i + 3];
}
ctx.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
```

Using this method, although the data gets drawn to the canvas, it appears like garbled snow or noise and is not a correct representation of the image.

This leads me to believe that I am constructing the imagedata data incorrectly in my loop or perhaps my initial method of getting the pixel array is incorrect.

To summarize,  I would like to be able to take an arraybuffer (of a jpeg) retrieved via the html5 fileReader API and then create a canvas compatible imageData array, so that it can later be pushed into a canvas using `putImageData`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

A *JPEG* file isn't a simple byte-array of colour data, and therefore you can't simply load it in like this. If you want to get around this without importing directly into a canvas you'll have to use a *JPEG* decoding library, such as [**this project by notmasteryet**](https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs) which I found via a quick google search.

**Original**

> unfortunately they are not usable for this specific use case

Why are they not usable?

```
// example array
u = new Uint8ClampedArray(4);
u[0] = 255, u[1] = 56, u[2] = 201, u[3] = 8; // [255, 56, 201, 8]
// to String
str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u); // "ÿ8É"
// to Base64
b64 = btoa(str); // "/zjJCA=="
// to DataURI
uri = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + b64; // "data:image/jpeg;base64,/zjJCA=="
```

And the reverse

```
// uri to Base64
b64 = uri.slice(uri.indexOf(',')+1);
// to String
str = atob(b64);
// to Array
arr = str.split('').map(function (e) {return e.charCodeAt(0);});
// to Uint8ClampedArray
u = new Uint8ClampedArray(arr); // [255, 56, 201, 8]
```

Comment: I omitted the reason due to it requiring a lengthy explanation.  In a nutshell Firefox has a confirmed bug when scaling multiple large images in a canvas using drawImage. e.g try scaling down 100 1920x1080 jpegs in a loop down to half their original size using drawImage.  You will see the memory usage grow exponentially up to around 3gb before the browser crashes. Even when removing all  references.  Although the garbage collector reduces the memory usage after the final image is complete it does not keep it steady throughout the process.  In contrast Chromes memory usage stays level.

Comment: This is an attempt to workaround this issue by scaling the imagedata down in javascript before it ever hits a canvas.  The only other solution I have is to set a 3 second timeout between each image scale to allow the garbage collector to clean up.  This unfortunately is not an acceptable waiting time.

Comment: The issue is a JPEG file very rarely contains a pixel array - it is compressed. You could load it into a canvas and have the browser's JPEG library decode it, then copy out the pixel-by-pixel data into an array (or into a second canvas).

Comment: I see, well that explains the problem.  Unfortunately doing as you suggested (loading it into a canvas) causes the memory issue.  What I really need is a pure javascript JPEG library to decode the data into a pixel array.

Comment: You should be aware that the resultant size of an Uint8 (8 bit integers) array will be at least `width * height * 3` bytes (8 bits = 1 byte), i.e. 6,220,800 bytes (5.93 MiB) for a 1920x1080 pixel image. (`3` for _RGB_, JPEG has no alpha-channel)

Comment: Thanks I am a little sketchy on image format specifics.  However that does not explain the excessive exponential in memory usage.  By about the 60th image in a 100 long loop the browser is adding approximately 300mb of extra memory per image!  As I said, it appears to be a confirmed bug.

Comment: Again; if this is the issue, I'd suggest use two canvases - one to import a JPG, which you can then export as a pixel array as desired (import/export, no transform), from which you write to your second canvas, doing your transformation in JavaScript now you have it in a format you can use. If you just want a library for it, google gives  https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs

Comment: Thanks Paul....  Your first solution unfortunatley causes the same issue, it appears as though Firefox causes a long time to release the original imagedata even when a canvas has been cleared and all references have gone.   I have actually just found and tried the the library you have pointed to and it actually works perfectly!  albeit a little slow.  Hopefully moving this into a webworker will help and keep the UI responsive.  If you want to put the library suggestion into an answer I will award it to you.  Thanks!