# Buffered image as JPG over Tomcat Websocket to HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, websocket, jpeg, bufferedimage

Hey we want to send buffered images periodically over tomcat websockets into a canvas, kind of a livestream.

Server Code:

```
private static void broadcastImage(BufferedImage img) {     
    StreamInbound someClient;
    byte[] arr = BufferedImageToByte(img);
    ListIterator<StreamInbound> iter = clients.listIterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        someClient = (MessageInbound) iter.next();
        try {
            someClient.getWsOutbound().writeBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(arr));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] BufferedImageToByte(BufferedImage img) {
    byte[] imageInBytes = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        imageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageInBytes;
}
```

the problem is how to pack this into the canvas.

Client Code:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://"+ location.host + "/carduinowebdroid/websocket");
ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

/** stuff **/

ws.onmessage = function(message){
    if (message.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        streamHandleMessage(message);
    }
}

function streamHandleMessage(message) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/** what now? **/

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ofc yes `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');`

Comment: did you try to use :
`var img = new Image();
img.src = dataUrl;
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a webSocket?
If not:

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    can.width = img.width;
    can.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
img.src = 'img.jpg';
```

Otherwise have a look at this:
[How can I create a canvas imageData array from an arrayBuffer representation of a JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194908/how-can-i-create-a-canvas-imagedata-array-from-an-arraybuffer-representation-of)
or this
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/real-time-data-exchange-in-html5-with-websockets.html