# How to convert Uint8ClampedArray of webp image picked from canvas to base64

Tags: javascript, canvas, arraybuffer

I'm trying to convert Uint8ClampedArray picked from webp images on canvas using the getImageData method.

I've tried the method found in this thread: [How can I create a canvas imageData array from an arrayBuffer representation of a JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194908/how-can-i-create-a-canvas-imagedata-array-from-an-arraybuffer-representation-of)

The output I get is only this part:

```
AAAAAA==
```

How to get the full data. Here's how I tried unsuccessful:

```
function Uint8toBase64(idata) {
    this.idata = idata;

    var u = new Uint8ClampedArray(4);

    for (var i = 0; i < idata.length; i += 4) {
        idata[0] = u[i];
        idata[1] = u[i + 1];
        idata[2] = u[i + 2];
        idata[3] = u[i + 3];
    }

    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u);
    var b64 = btoa(str);

    console.log(b64);
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where are you getting that array from? Can't you just get the base64 data instead?

Comment: using toDataURL is inefficient if image is too large or high resolution, I'm going to do this with web worker

Comment: Do you think manually converting the array to a base64 string is going to be faster than letting the browser do it?

Comment: I don't know, I give it a try.

Comment: @Cerbrus is probably right. While `toDataURL` is always an expensive conversion, it is a straightforward encoding operation so the browsers likely have the performance edge over a manual conversion.

Comment: Thanks @markE. I agree, but ArrayBuffer can be sliced in multi-parts, converted separately, then reassembled. I'd like to see if this assumption working.