# How to supply the correct data when ImageData is not available?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, arraybuffer

I'm using a JS library to vectorize a raster image and the library is returning a solid color fill instead of the desired result.

I think it has to do with the ArrayBuffer.

I am loading an image into a binary like so:

```
const arrayBuffer = await image.read({ format: filesystem.formats.binary });
```

The library expects an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object but the environment I'm in `canvas` and `ImageData` are not supported, so I'm attempting to create a fake ImageData object to pass to the library:

```
var imageData = {data: arrayBuffer, width: sceneNode.globalBounds.width, height: sceneNode.globalBounds.height};
var results = library.apply(imageData);
```

I attempt to run the library and it shows an error that it expects data object to have length property so I add that beforehand:

```
 arrayBuffer.length = arrayBuffer.bytesLength;
```

The library appears to have no errors after that as it returns a SVG data. But SVG is simply a path of the bounds of the image.

I'm guessing the ArrayBuffer in the fake ImageData object is the problem and that I need to convert it into the correct format.

The docs says this about ImageData.data property:

> ImageData.data is a Uint8ClampedArray representing a one-dimensional array containing
>   the data in the RGBA order, with integer values between 0 and 255
>   (inclusive).

It seems like I need to convert the array buffer into a *"a Uint8ClampedArray representing a one-dimensional array containing the data in the RGBA order, with integer values between 0 and 255"*.

Also, if I'm reading the file in as binary format in JavaScript that's a standard [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) correct?

**UPDATE**:
It might be that the image file is loaded into a array buffer but it needs to be decoded from the image format (PNG or JPEG) and then converted into Uint8ClampedArray? and then pixel data can be read, [How can I create a canvas imageData array from an arrayBuffer representation of a JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194908/how-can-i-create-a-canvas-imagedata-array-from-an-arraybuffer-representation-of). That seems to be what the ImageData class does.

The [UPNG](https://github.com/photopea/UPNG.js) library seems to decode PNGs but the data property is an object and not an array?

Library is ImageTracer - https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjs

Comment: it seems like the library also accept url as input, do you have specific reason needs to read it to arraybuffer?

Comment: @appleapple The library uses a loadImage() method that adds the image to canvas and when the image is loaded it gets the image data from the canvas. The environment I'm in doesn't support canvas so I'm loading in the image manually. I can get an ArrayBuffer or base64. https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjs/blob/21b1d9bd21a374fe35620ece1058a55307e111e0/imagetracer_v1.2.5.js#L1119

Comment: It seems you get the answer yourself :) since I don't know how your `image.read` work, I can only say I think it's pretty likely the case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've almost answered your question. :)

1. Create a `TypedArray` view from the `ArrayBuffer`:

   imageData.data = new Uint8ClampedArray(arrayBuffer);

or

```
var imageData = {data: new Uint8ClampedArray(arrayBuffer), width: sceneNode.globalBounds.width, height: sceneNode.globalBounds.height};
```

2. Decode the image file beforehand, because the bytes in compressed formats like JPEG or PNG are not directly RGBA values. Or you can try uncompressed RGBA32 BMP, but remove the header first, discard the first 54 bytes from the Array.

I think it looks like this with UPNG, but I haven't tested it:

```
var img  = UPNG.decode(buff);        // put ArrayBuffer of the PNG file into UPNG.decode
var rgba = UPNG.toRGBA8(img)[0];     // UPNG.toRGBA8 returns array of frames, size: width * height * 4 bytes.

var myImageData = { width:img.width, height:img.height, data:rgba };

var traceoptions = 'default'; // or whatever
var svgstr = ImageTracer.imagedataToSVG( myImageData, traceoptions );
```